# Multiple extractors for a javafx observableArrayList? (how to fire update events when more than one property is changed)

Tags: java, javafx

From this question: [JavaFX SortedList: listen the list changes and the list items updated event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806814/javafx-sortedlist-listen-the-list-changes-and-the-list-items-updated-event)

I learned how to use an extractor to get my listview to sort its elements when a property is changed.

However my listview has a name (string property) and a colour (object property). I'm using a cell factory to customize the background of each cell to the elements colour. I want to know if it's possible to tell the backing observable array list to fire update events just like it does when the name property is changed, but to also do it when the colour property is changed?

Comment: use an extractor - which is an array of observables - which has both properties

Comment: ah it's a simple as making sure the array have all of them in I see, thanks for clarifying, if you would like to write an answer I will accept